# Solving a recurrence relation for the prime counting function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, recurrences

I have found some number sequence $c_n = 1+b_n$ for $n \ge 0$, where $b_n = $ [A307977(n)](https://oeis.org/A307977).
I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation for the prime counting function:

$$\forall n \ge 3: \pi(n) = \frac{1}{n-2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \pi(k) c_{n-1-k}$$

in terms of the sequence $c_n$, where $\pi(n)=0$ for $n<2$ and $\pi(2)=1$. (I can prove that the recurrence formula holds, but I can not solve the recurrence formula for $\pi(n)$ on the left and $c_k$-s only on the right as suggested in the SageMath code:

Here is for $n \ge 3$ the sequence $(n-2)! \cdot \pi(n)$ computed with [SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJydk09vgjAYxu8kfIfGXd5CVYrLDovs7GExcTsui4HSShOtphTix1-xKDDZlowT7fu8D7_3D3WqYWIm2Pd8L-cCCQGGrBMaRfjZ95B9NDeVVqisDmCCQJlie9LywEFiJI4aSSQV0qnacaBkHVJ8s1qt_rAKLkbbkwTlvNSIV5Pn_BgDlTxF1nLRWb7NluYFJeg1rTRX5p1rycs3qXaw2RDV5hdW0NKs26vcXuVWXKdG1hwKYvC8cKEHi6UM5K2SNcoZO3IhJJP2GyVcIzOpSq4NxCTCgwrZlduRZ9l_yYUVtCP5gVw05GLw9Xta38vONg0uIDRuSB4tCbaErtjsjK-vlzYPNa4KXZR2UMNR0jmoaYwDaGYKNMzOHzKkn7g32imd3q-Kwt2e7Ed8u3S7BTcAzipte8V4p5cCqWXcHnoGURdOkpE4dTd8X_KR4KCquvlF2HYSlkbbrcc46IP8Wt63pV6Q-DZ-12xFXFdJr2J7ECkzRy3TveNwRxjUj_EXg08B5A==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==):

```
3 c_0
4 c_0^2 + c_1
5 c_0^3 + 3*c_0*c_1 + 2*c_2
6 c_0^4 + 6*c_0^2*c_1 + 3*c_1^2 + 8*c_0*c_2 + 6*c_3
7 c_0^5 + 10*c_0^3*c_1 + 15*c_0*c_1^2 + 20*c_0^2*c_2 + 20*c_1*c_2 + 30*c_0*c_3 + 24*c_4
8 c_0^6 + 15*c_0^4*c_1 + 45*c_0^2*c_1^2 + 40*c_0^3*c_2 + 15*c_1^3 + 120*c_0*c_1*c_2 + 90*c_0^2*c_3 + 40*c_2^2 + 90*c_1*c_3 + 144*c_0*c_4 + 120*c_5
9 c_0^7 + 21*c_0^5*c_1 + 105*c_0^3*c_1^2 + 70*c_0^4*c_2 + 105*c_0*c_1^3 + 420*c_0^2*c_1*c_2 + 210*c_0^3*c_3 + 210*c_1^2*c_2 + 280*c_0*c_2^2 + 630*c_0*c_1*c_3 + 504*c_0^2*c_4 + 420*c_2*c_3 + 504*c_1*c_4 + 840*c_0*c_5 + 720*c_6
```

**Q1) Is it possible to give an explicit formula for $\pi(n)$ in terms of $c_k$ only?**

Q2) Are there other known recursive formulas for the prime counting function in the literature?

(I tried to search for some of these coefficients in OEIS but I can not see the general pattern, if there is one, for all coefficients of these polynomials in the $c_n$.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Which I can prove, but not yet solve" does not make any sense.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao: It means: I can prove the recurrence formula as stated. But I can not solve $\pi(n)$ for $c_n$: I would like to have a formula, where on the left there is $\pi(n)$ and on the right there is only $c_n$.

Comment: As for Q2, see for example https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeisselsFormula.html and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LehmersFormula.html

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I haven’t verified the correctness of what you wrote but it’s worth noticing The RHS looks like a discrete convolution. I know in the continuous setting these things can be undone via Fourier transforms. Since you’re in the discrete setting I’m not sure how it goes but you might want to look at “discrete convolution”, “deconvolution”, and “discrete deconvolution”. In particular you want to call $b(r) = c_{r-1}$ then your formula becomes $(n-2)\pi(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \pi(k)b(n-k)$ and that looks a discrete convolution to me

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal: Yes it looks like discrete convolution. I realised this also and am trying the discrete convolution also. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: In the case of infinite discrete sums these also factor nicely the way they do in the continuous case (see the section labeled convolution theorem): https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Signal_Processing_and_Modeling/Signals_and_Systems_(Baraniuk_et_al.)/09%3A_Discrete_Time_Fourier_Transform_(DTFT)/9.05%3A_Discrete_Time_Convolution_and_the_DTFT

Comment: Yes even in the finite case this factors. See the circular convolutional theorem section here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform . Unfortunately that $n-2$ factor complicates things a bit but if you take a discrete Fourier transform that sum (called a circular convolution) explicitly transforms into a product which is easier to work with.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal: Thanks for your interest in this question. After thinking about it, I do not clearly see , how the introduction of Fourier transform can help in this case. If you can give an answer with details, I will try to follow.

Comment: $$\pi(n+2) = \sum_{\vec{x}} \frac{c_{x_1-1}}{x_1} \cdot \frac{c_{x_2-1}}{x_1 + x_2} \cdot \frac{c_{x_3-1}}{x_1+x_2+x_3} \cdots \frac{c_{x_k-1}}{n}$$ where the sum is over compositions of $n$. Note quite the same as Bell polynomials, but possibly something in this form has been studied before.

Comment: @mathoverflowUser the idea of trying a transform is the observation that $F((n-2)\pi(n)) = F(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \pi(k)b(n-k))$ so therefore $F(n-2)\star F(\pi(n)) = F(\pi(k)) F(b(n-k))$ so the right hand side becomes just a very nice multiplication but because of that $(n-2)$ the LHS now has a convolution so this doesn't help solve the problem in an obvious fashion.

Comment: I was hoping this might shed some light on the matter: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806220/how-to-simultaneously-remove-a-convolution-and-a-multiplication

Comment: How is this related to the recurrence $$\pi(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \pi(k)\, a_k\,,\quad n>2$$ where $$a=\left\{a_1,2,0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{3},0,0,0,\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{5},0,0,0,\frac{1}{6},0,\frac{1}{7},0,0,0,\frac{1}{8},0,0,0,0,0,\frac{1}{9},0,\frac{1}{10},0,...\right\}?$$

Comment: @StevenClark: How do you define the $a_i$? I can see the numbers but I do not see the definition. The $c_i$ are defined as $1+b_i$ for $i>0$ and $c_{-1}=2$ or equivalently as the coefficients of $H'(t)/H(t)$ where $H(t) = \sum_{n} \pi(n) t^n$.

Comment: @StevenClark's coefficients are $$a_i = \begin{cases}\textrm{arbitrary} & \textrm{if } i = 1 \\
2 & \textrm{if } i = 2 \\
0 & \textrm{if } i+1 \textrm{ composite} \\
\frac{1}{\pi(i)} & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ It's a direct encoding of the primes.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It's a simpler formula and admittedly kind of silly, but it you consider the more complicated generating function for the formula in the question the only difference is that it compensates for the $\frac{1}{n-2}$ factor and reversal of the order of the coefficients, so it seems kind of silly to me as well as it really doesn't provide any insight into the primes. I can post an answer illustrating my two generating functions if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out to be more straightforward than I expected.

Let $C(z) = \sum_{i \ge 0} c_i z^i$ be the g.f. for $c_i$, excluding $c_{-1}$ since that doesn't show up in your recurrence.

Starting with $$\forall n \ge 3: \pi(n) = \frac{1}{n-2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \pi(k) c_{n-1-k}$$ we construct $\Pi(z)$, the g.f. of $\pi(n)$:

\begin{eqnarray*}\Pi(z) &=& z^2 + \sum_{n \ge 3}\pi(n)z^n \\
z^{-2} \Pi(z) &=& 1 + \sum_{n \ge 3}\pi(n)z^{n-2} \\
&=& 1 + \sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{z^{n-2}}{n-2} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \pi(k) c_{n-1-k} \\
&=& 1 + \sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{z^{n-2}}{n-2} [z^{n-1}] \left(\Pi(z) C(z)\right) \\
&=& 1 + \int z^{-2} \Pi(z) C(z) \textrm{d}z \\
\end{eqnarray*} where the constant of integration must be zero. Differentiate both sides and rearrange to get a logarithmic derivative:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}z} z^{-2} \Pi(z)}{z^{-2} \Pi(z)} &=& C(z) \\
\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}z} \log \left(z^{-2} \Pi(z)\right) &=& C(z) \\
\Pi(z) &=& z^2 \exp \int C(z) \textrm{d}z \\
\end{eqnarray*} where again the constant of integration must be zero. If you prefer, you can make that explicit as $$\Pi(z) = z^2 \exp \sum_{i \ge 0} \frac{c_i z^{i+1}}{i+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I do not understand the step from the choice of the coefficient $[z^{n-1}](\Pi(z) C(z))$ to the integral directly below it and before the words "where the constant of integration must be zero".

Comment: $[z^{n-1}](\Pi(z) C(z)) = [z^{n-3}](z^{-2} \Pi(z) C(z))$. The introduction of the integral might be easier to see backwards: $\int \sum a_i z^i \textrm{d}z = \sum \int a_i z^i \textrm{d}z = \sum \frac{a_i z^{i+1}}{i+1}$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my notation, I wrote $H(t)$ for what you call $\Pi(z)$. Your last equation makes me a bit suspicious, since I do not understand where the zero $\gamma = $ (https://oeis.org/A078756) of $\Pi(z)$ is gone? It seems like you show, that this function $\Pi(z)=H(z)$ has no zero besides $0$ because of the $\exp$ function? Unfortunately, I can not pin to the place where I think that the confusion arises.

Comment: The definition given for A078756 is that it's the root of the g.f. of the prime indicator function. Is your $H$ the g.f. of the prime indicator function or the prime counting function?

Comment: The expression $\Pi(z) = z^2 \exp \sum_{i \ge 0} \frac{c_i z^{i+1}}{i+1}$ can also be derived directly from the definition of A307977 and the relationship $\Pi(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{p \textrm{ prime}} z^p$.

Comment: But in the last case, the $\gamma=$ A078756 is a zero of $\Pi(z)$ whereas in the first case of your expression this is not.

Comment: By the expression $\Pi(z) = 1/(1-z) \cdot \sum_{p \text{prime}}z^p$ we see that $\gamma$ is a zero of both functions. Does this answer your question above?

Comment: Here is a little bit more context: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164216/a-series-related-to-prime-numbers

Comment: I think what this shows is either that your heuristic about $\exp$ and roots is wrong or that because we're working with formal power series there are convergence issues. From the definition of $b_i$ as $\sum_{i \ge -1} b_i z^i = \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}z} \log f(z)$ we easily derive $f(z) = \exp \int \sum_{i \ge -1} b_i z^i \textrm{d}z = \exp \left(b_{-1}\log z + \int \sum_{i \ge 0} b_i z^i \textrm{d}z\right) = z^{b_{-1}} \exp \int \sum_{i \ge 0} b_i z^i \textrm{d}z$

Comment: Ok, but numerical computation in GP-Pari and SageMath, suggest that $\gamma$ (https://oeis.org/A078756) is a zero of $f(z)$, so there must be some convergence issues.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following fairly simple Mathematica code

```
Block[{a={a1},n=3},
 While[n<=32,
  a=AppendTo[a,(PrimePi[n]-Sum[a[[k]] PrimePi[k],{k,1,n-2}])/PrimePi[n-1]];
  n++];
 a]
```

which generates the first few values of $a_k$ as follows

$$a=\left\{a_1,2,0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{3},0,0,0,\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{5},0,0,0,\frac{1}{6},0,\frac{1}{7},0,0,0,\frac{1}{8},0,0,0,0,0,\frac{1}{9},0,\frac{1}{10},0\right\}$$

starting at $a_1$ where

$$\pi(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \pi(k)\, a_k\,,\quad n>2\tag{1}.$$

---

For the recursive formula in the question above, the following slightly more complicated Mathematica code

```
Block[{c={},n=3},
 While[n<=32,
  c=AppendTo[c,(n-2) PrimePi[n]-Sum[PrimePi[k] c[[n-k]],{k,3,n-1}]];
  n++];
 c]
```

generates the first few values of $c_k$ as follows

$c=\{2,0,5,-4,12,-15,23,-36,68,-100,167,-259,405,-651,1050,-1652,2637,-4182,6633,-10564,16805,-26675,42391,-67371,107062,-170183,270473,-429783,683068,-1085560\}$

starting at $c_0=2$ where

$$\pi(n)=\frac{1}{n-2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \pi(k)\, c_{n-1-k}\,,\quad n>2\tag{2}.$$

---

Note that

$$c-1=\{1,-1,4,-5,11,-16,22,-37,67,-101,166,-260,404,-652,1049,-1653,2636,-4183,6632,-10565,16804,-26676,42390,-67372,107061,-170184,270472,-429784,683067,-1085561\}$$

corresponds to [OEIS Entry A307977](https://oeis.org/A307977).

---

The two Mathematica programs above compensate for the fact that the first element of a Mathematica list has index $1$ instead of index $0$ which is more typical of programming languages.

---

I believe the formula

$$\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^x \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & k=2+\sum\limits_{p<k} (c_{k-p-1}-1) \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\right)\tag{3}$$

where $p$ is a prime is valid for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I also think it is true: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164216/a-series-related-to-prime-numbers

Comment: @mathoverflowUser But it wasn't quite what you were looking for in your Q1?

Comment: Not really, I was hoping for a formula like the one given in the comments of the question but with a little bit more details. But thanks for your interest.